# EF Core - 2 Entities, each with a reference to another lookup Entity. On Add - IOE - cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

We're using EF Core 3.1

We have 2 Entities - `item` and `batch`. Each have a reference to `currency`. When we add both an item and a batch, each with a  reference to a loaded (and tracked) `currency` EF Core spits out the following `System.InvalidOperationException`:

```
The instance of entity type 'Currency' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 103}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

We're not doing anything too irregular:

```
                var currency = _context.Set<Currency>.SingleOrDefault(currencyId);

                var item = new Item(currency);
                var batch = Batch.Create(currency, new[] { item });
                _context.Set<Batch>.Add(batch);
                item.Batch = batch;                        
                _context.Set<Item>.Add(instruction);
```

And our maps have fks etc `ItemMap`:

```
            modelBuilder
                .HasOne(i => i.Currency)
                .WithMany()
                .IsRequired();

            modelBuilder
                .HasOne(i => i.Batch)
                .WithMany();
```

and `BatchMap`:

```
            modelBuilder
                .HasOne(i => i.Currency)
                .WithMany()
                .IsRequired();
```

and `CurrencyMap`:

```
            modelBuilder
                .ToTable("Currency")
                .HasKey(cur => cur.Id);

            modelBuilder
                .HasData(new Currency(103));
```

I wonder if anyone can point out my stupidity or at least explain where I may be going wrong?

Comment: I think for this situation you can try to get your currency  without tracking `var currency = _context.Set<Currency>.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(currencyId);`

Comment: Hi @Anton thanks, but I was under the impression that if I wanted to refer to another Entity on the insert then it must be tracked - i.e. `Currency` must be tracked